# How to redirect to other pages based on clicked data row.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a question that needs a bit of explaining so I'll try to be as clear as possible. I am working with a few web pages. One one (CustomerListPage) I pull up a list of customers via GridView. I made the rows clickable so that choosing a customer would be the link itself to the next page. Once the user has clicked a customer, It takes them to the next page (CustomerUsePage). This page is suppose to show the name of the customer clicked in one of the labels I have created and some of their other info (Customer ID, street, city, etc) in the rest of the labels. This is the code on my CustomerListPage:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

   if (GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex == 0)
   {
       //string selectedUser = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString();
       Response.Redirect("CustomerUsePage.aspx?Customer_ID=" );
       BindGridview();
   }

   if (GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex == 3)
   {
       //string selectedUser = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString();
       Response.Redirect("CustomerUsePage.aspx?Customer_ID=");
       BindGridview();
   }

}
```

and here is the code on CustomerUsePage:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string v = Request.QueryString["Customer_ID"];
    Response.Write(v);

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindControlvalues();    
    }
}

private void BindControlvalues()
{        
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" sql query ", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    con.Close();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Label5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[3][8].ToString();
    Label4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[3][0].ToString();
    Label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[3][1].ToString();
    Label2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[3][3].ToString();
    Label3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[3][5].ToString();          
}
```

As seen, I am filling my labels with the data received from my query by indexing those pieces of data. I would want to get away from that and use a more efficient method but it works for now. More importantly, is there a way to populate my labels based on the customer I click on? for now clicking any customer would yield the same result. I was thinking of something along the lines of: "if selected row index = 0" but I know this will not work since GridView does not exist to this page. However, the logic is what I want. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `RowCommand event`

```
void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.CommandName=="Select")
    {
            var label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("YourLabelId");
            var value = label.Text;
            Response.Redirect("CustomerUsePage.aspx?Customer_ID=" +value);

    }
  }
```

Aspx

```
<asp:gridview onrowcommand="GridView_RowCommand"/>
```

And add your column who raises event

```
<columns>
                <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" 
                  commandname="Select" 
                  text="Select"/>

               <asp:templatefield headertext="Author Name">
                 <itemtemplate>
                     <asp:label id="YourLabelId" Text= '<%# Eval("Customer_ID") %>' runat="server"/>
                 </itemtemplate>
                </asp:templatefield>
</columns>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The query I used to populate those labels are in the CustomerUsePage. Also, in CustomerUsePage I specify the exact index of the data I want in those labels table[0] row[1][1]. Does Var value just follow a certain sequence?

Comment: Is there a directive needed to use Item? I don't have that option after I type "e."

Comment: no because item is property of e (his type is GridViewCommandEventArgs )

Answer (score 0):

I use itemtemplates and hyperlink objects.  Please let me know if you need more than this.

Here's a [sample.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1055737.aspx/1)

A paste from that site is below:

**Postback method:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="The Column header ">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="MyLink"   
            Text="<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>"  
            NavigateUrl='Project.aspx?ProjectID=<%# Eval("DatasourceField") %>'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Non-postback:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="The Column header ">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='Project.aspx?ProjectID=<%# Eval("DatasourceField") %>'>
            <%# Eval("ProjectName") %> 
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you explain the postback method a bit. Does it go in the Customer list source code? will that populate my other page as desired as it evaluates datasource?

Comment: the post back method forces a trip to the server to forward to the link.  this would not populate your other page - it just processes the click event for the hyperlink object.  this is useful if you want to perform additional logic at the time of the click.  if you don't, then you can keep it simple by pushing a regular <a> to the browser that would have the fully-formed URL with the key to the record in the querystring.